# Changing text of the royal preloader

Tags: javascript, css, preloader

Hello experts! 
             I have downloaded a free template to use it for my website. I see that they are using royal preloader plugin for their pre-loading text or logo. I have no idea how do I change their text/logo to that of mine. I have gone through all of the CSS and JS files and couldn't find any clue. If someone here has a clue, please guide me. I can upload files or code on demand, right now I do not know what to upload or paste.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that as follow.

```
Royal_Preloader.config({
                mode: 'text',
                text: 'Your Custom Text here',
                background: "#000000"
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Royal_Preloader.config({
            mode:           'text', // 'number', "text" or "logo"
            text:           'text',
            timeout:        0,
            showInfo:       true,
            opacity:        1,
            background:     ['#191919']
        });
```

---

logo //

```
Royal_Preloader.config({
            mode:           'logo', // 'number', "text" or "logo"
            logo:           '/img/logo.png,
            timeout:        0,
            showInfo:       true,
            opacity:        1,
            background:     ['#191919']
        });
```